# Where to put commas in this sentence and why?

Tags: inversion, commas, run-on-sentences

Where should I put commas in the following sentence:

*In these investments the analysis of the reasonably possible changes in the key assumptions used in calculating the value in use shows that the carrying amount of the investment would be higher than the recoverable value.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence does not make any sense, may I suggest rewording the sentence, adding commas will not help. You need to work on other grammar tactics before trying to add commas.

=== as per op request ===
In these investments, the analysis of the reasonably possible changes in the key assumptions used in calculating the value in use, shows that the carrying amount of the investment would be higher than the recoverable value.

Try to put commas anywhere you pause while reading this sentence. This was tricky due to the nature of this sentence. I hope this helps.

Comment: May I politely disagree? I do think that the problem is in the commas. :)

Comment: Well I think that the commas are a problem but the grammar is also bad.

Comment: Please give more concrete feedback, so that I have a starting point for improvement.

Comment: I added stuff to my answer

Comment: Yes, this is probably a good rule of thumb, but I really find it hard to determine where to put commas in English. I mean, there are some clear cases, but there are also a lot of times, when I am really not sure if I have to put comma or not... Thank you for your time and effort.